# Javascript adding new row with foreach function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, foreach, html-table

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/k7jwLvt1/

```
$(function(){
    var tbl = $("#table");

    $("#addRowBtn").click(function(){
        $("<tr><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td><input type='checkbox' class='setbox'></td><td><button class='delRowBtn'>Delete</button></td></tr>").appendTo(tbl);        
    });

    $(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();        
    });    

});
```

I am currently adding new rows to a table that have checkboxes at the end. Meanwhile, I have a foreach loop to check on these checkboxes to execute an AJAX script but that's trivial to this matter.

The foreach loop I have works great if I populate one row by default (without clicking the Add Row button). However, it doesn't work for the new rows added subsequently. How could I have my foreach loop to detect the new added rows after the page load?

I've tried encapsulating the foreach loop as a function and re-execute it on each Add row button click but that seems to add the AJAX script in a queue.

```
    function setbox() {
         $(\".setBox\").each(function() {
                var isChecked = this.checked;

                $('.setBox').click(function()    {
                    $.ajax(blahblahblah});
                }
            });
      }
   }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I couldn't understand the question. Your jsfiddle is adding stuff properly so I can't understand the problem, try being a little more explicit.

Comment: when is setbox function called? and why are calling the click evening inside the loop?

Comment: You're using `.delegate` for `.delRowButton`. Why not for `.setbox` too? http://jsfiddle.net/k7jwLvt1/1/ And the class is `setbox` not `setBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  this may help you and you don't need to use function setbox(). You can try this code.

```
  $('body').on('click', '.setbox',function()   {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    alert(isChecked);
    //$.ajax(blahblahblah});
 });
```